# macOS: Memory consumption caused by setNeedsDisplayInRect

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, memory-leaks

My macOS application suffers from serious memory leaks. After lots of debugging I seem to have found the cause, though I still don't really understand it.

The app draws pixels to an internal buffer, which is then actually drawn to screen in the `drawRect` method of an `NSView` subclass. The repaint is triggered by a `[self setNeedsDisplayInRect:rect]`.

After a few hours the program consumes multiple gigabytes of RAM. However when I put the call to `setNeedsDisplayInRect` in a loop to call it, say, 10,000 times instead of just one time whenever I want to repaint, the memory consumption rises to gigabytes in just minutes.

To make sure the memory isn't leaking in the `drawRect` method, I've removed the complete body, leaving only an empty method.

As far as I understand from the documentation, all rects given to `setNeedsDisplayInRect` are stored until the repaint is actually processed in the next run of the event loop. So when I call it 10,000 times I expect the memory consumption to be higher, but I wouldn't expect it to keep rising all the time – I expect all the stored rects to be cleaned up after one iteration of the event loop.

So, why does the amount of memory keep on rising when calling `setNeedsDisplayInRect`? I know calling it 10,000 times multiple times per second isn't exactly normal use, but the memory usage also keeps rising in normal situations, though a lot slower.

Code excerpt:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
// Currently, nothing happening
}

// My own method, that gets called from elsewhere.
- (void) drawToScreen:(int) x : (int) y : (int)w :(int)h :(int *)data
{    
    int rectYPos = MAX(height - y - h, 0);
    NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(x, rectYPos, w, h);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:rect];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're calling this from a secondary / background thread, you might want to review (from Apple's docs):

"If a secondary thread of an application wants to cause portions of the view to be redrawn on the main thread, it must not do so using methods like display, setNeedsDisplay:, setNeedsDisplayInRect:, or setViewsNeedDisplay:. Instead, it should send a message to the main thread or call those methods using the performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: method instead."

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html

Comment: This indeed appeared to be the problem. Weird that this isn't documented in the setNeedsDisplay* docs. I replaced the `[self setNeedsDisplayInRect:rect]` by this: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){[self setNeedsDisplayInRect:rect]; });`
...and now the memory no longer leaks. That is, it still rises slowly, but after a while suddenly drops; repeat.